# Data not being partitioned in optimal way on executors when using Spark's ALS Mlib algorithm

Tags: performance, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, partitioning

I am using ALS algorithm in Spark MLlib. Whenever I run my code, the data is cached on just 1 or 2 executors. I have 8 executors running but caching on just one node decreases the performance of my jobs drastically. The data cached is what ALS uses internally, i.e - itemBlocks, userBlocks, userFactors etc. I have given the number of partitions and am using implicit parameter in the model. 
My data size is quite small in some use cases. eg - 40-50MB. But still I can't understand why it would cache on just one node. Also sometimes 3-4 executors are used and sometimes 1-2. The partitioning is very random.

Comment: Your data must be skewed and you'd need to repartition it before feeding it to ALS.

Comment: I am partitioning it before. Also Spark partitions the idea on its own. Thats what it uses numBlocks for. All intermediates datasets are stored in cache. Its those datasets that are not present on every executor.

Comment: @ShitijGoyal it's 5 years passed, but experiencing same issue here. did you figured out the solution?